iOS | Composable Architecture | Present modal from root while pushed controllers might also present at that moment
Currently I am working on an hobby/investigation/learning project with the Composable Architecture.
So currently I have an issue that I cannot find a nice solution for unless I start to use UIKit again with a coordinator pattern (or something similar).
So pushing something with TCA can easily be done with StackState
Recipe List -- push -> Recipe Detail View -- Push -> Ingredient Details

Even if you have multiple pushed items the root feature could still receive a deep link and easily just add another item to the stack.
But lets say for example the Ingredient Details would be presented modally
Recipe List -- push -> Recipe Detail View ^^ modal ^^ Ingredient Details

At this moment if the root feature would receive a deep link (eg push notification 'Recipe of day' and want to present this modally you cannot set a presentation state without resulting in a conflict of 'two modals being presented'.
Recipe List -- push -> Recipe Detail View ^^ modal ^^ Ingredient Details
  |^^ Recipe detail view ^^

To handle this correctly the only way I found is that you would need to go through all the Reducers and find a 'top reducer' which also needs to support a presentation state.
Has anyone found a nice 'SwiftUI only' solution for this?
Also does anyone have a nice solution for this if we use modules? If Recipe and Ingredient detail views are both in different modules, and lets assume that in the ingredient details you can open another recipe details page with 'recipes that use this ingredient'
Recipe List -- push -> Recipe Detail View -- Push -> Ingredient Details -- Push --> Recipe Detail View

But for this to work with modules in this case Module Recipe and Module Ingredients would have to refer to each other, which of course is not possible.
To solve this you would need to create reducers in the 'Main app' to link it all together to prevent these dependencies to import each others.
